# How "safe" is it to use void pointers in designing a messaging system in C++?

Tags: c++, messaging, void-pointers

I am trying to implement a generic messaging system in my C++ application.

The program has been divided into different systems that handle different things like rendering, image loading, etc. I want them to be able to push a message into a message stack, with some type of a data to transfer with it.

For implementing this I have made an API that allows this:

```
MessageStack.add(System * sender, 
                 System * receiver, 
                 MessageCodeEnum message_type, 
                 void * data);
```

The variable `message_type` is an enum that defines all message commands there are and the `void * data` is supposed to be the data attached to the message. These messages are arranged in a stack and are evaluated at the end of each frame.

Suppose the `renderer` messages the `fileLoader` to load an image. The `renderer` will add a message to tell `fileLoader` to load the image and the message will have a `void *` inside it that is actually a `const char *` that points to a C string containing the path of the image file.

Inside the switch case block in the function that handles this message, I have type-casted the message data that was a `void *` to a `const char *` by using the plain old way:

```
const char * temp = (const char *) data;
```

Now this brings me to this question. If during any message transaction, the program knows what kind of a data is being transmitted, which is why I feel confident while type-casting a `void *`, does the usage of `void *` really be an unsafe method to achieve such functionality? Are there any better ways to achieve such a level of loosened type checking?

Comment: You may want to add the *length* of the message. The general structure of a general message as used in old-school message-passing protocols is <message-type> <message-length> <message-payload>. And this is C not C++.

Comment: `void *` is almost always a bad idea in C++. Have you considered a polymorphic class that encapsulates the data and the message type?

Comment: @AlexP I am using C++ for this project, so I think I shouldn't be discouraging anyone who comes up with a solution that might work in C++ but not in C. I am just increasing my chances of getting a good response. I added C to the tags by the way. Also I will look into adding length of the message but that doesn't completely fix the problem though.

Comment: @user4581301 I haven't look into that yet. A polymorphic class may help

Comment: You can try using templates for writing generic code rather than using void pointers.

Comment: If you're asking about a C++ project, don't tag with C.  If you're writing C code, don't tag with C++.

Comment: I would take an OOP approach to this. Define a base class `Message` with an abstract method `execute()` (or whatever you want to name it), and then define a descendant for each message type (`FileLoadMessage`, etc) that has data members as needed (`std::string filename`, etc) and overrides `execute()` to do what is needed with the data (load the file, etc). Then you can create instances of each descendant as needed, pushing their `Message*` pointers into your stack, and then loop through your stack calling `execute()` on each `Message` object without knowing (or caring) what type it really is

Comment: If you (can) use a compiler that supports it and there's nothing else in the way in your application you might be able to use a [variant](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant) as well, though depending on how many types of messages there are it might become unwieldy to type out so many template parameters...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `void` pointers is inherently unsafe, in the sense that it is VERY EASY for a programmer to misuse them, and your compiler can rarely diagnose misuse.  Programmers also tend to be over-confident in their ability to write good code, which doesn't work well when using `void` pointers since they are so easy to misuse.

If you make a mistake, and use the pointer incorrectly (e.g.  casting it to `X *`, where it doesn't actually point at an `X`, and then accessing members of `X` via that pointer) then behaviour of your code is undefined.

Even worse, programmers tend to think that "I can find where I've made a mistake with a pointer because the program will crash".   The sad thing is: more often than not, that is untrue.   A lot of pointer errors — and particularly misuses of `void` pointers — sail through compiling and testing without errors.   Either because they are missed in testing (the programmer didn't think THAT could happen, so didn't test for it) or because the result of the error is not a crash (e.g. poisoning data in your program, such as overwriting innocent variables, is rarely detected at the point it occurs).    With misuse of `void` pointers, the misuse can be so subtle that the error remains undetected for quite a long time, the symptoms can affect unrelated code, so the cause is VERY hard to find.

You can mitigate the effects of that lack of safety through careful design (design it in a way that makes it harder to misuse the pointers), careful coding (to minimise errors in translating that design into code), and exhaustive testing (a comprehensive testing of your code can help increase your confidence that your code does not misuse those pointers).       In short, it takes effort and time on your part.   However, miss one thing, and you are in trouble.   Miss a particular corner case during design, and your program will have a design flaw that results in pointer misuse.  Introduce a typo that causes a pointer to be misused, and you're in trouble.    Don't exercise that design flaw during testing, and you will have a bug waiting to be found - in worst case, by the user of your program.

Generally speaking, it is better to use a technique that doesn't involve using `void` pointers.   Specify an interface for your data and message, and check that.   Provide your data in a typesafe manner.   Use a polymorphic base class with a carefully designed set of operations.  The list of options goes on.

If you exhaust all other design possibilities, then - yeah - consider using `void` pointers.     But accept they are dangerous, so a lot of effort on YOUR part will be needed to ensure your messaging system is robust, and minimise chances for other people (developers or end users) to break it.

Comment: I guess `void *` are the least suitable solution to this problem

Comment: Thanks for this. I ended up using Boost.Variant and it seem to get the job done